# How can I post a question on Quora with python code? Would any form of post request work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, quora

I want to create a bot that submits questions to Quora with a fill-in-the-gap algorithm (I have a sentence with places where words should be, and then a list of a few hundred words, and the bot should randomly select words and plug them in to the sentence e.g "I like **_ and _**", and the word list is ["bananas", "apples", "oranges", "chocolate", "fruit", "kiwis"], obviously without repeating any sentences)

How would I go about coding this? Is Quora's API suitable? Should I use the post request library?

I looked at Quora's API, but it seems to only be suitable for importing data.